# UILabel.layer.zPosition is giving me a compile error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This line of code is generating an error:
Accessing unknown 'zPosition' component of a property.

```
textLabel.layer.zPosition = 5;
```

The bizarre thing is that I have used this line of code in other apps and it works perfect. I cannot see a difference in anything. They are all declared in the same way.

Is there something I am missing?

This is driving me up the wall.

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported the right header?

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```